# Run Powershell script from Git in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to run a powershell script stored in AWS CodeCommit in Jenkins but without success.

I've tested all the possible solutions I can think of.

Is there any tested way that I can follow to do this?

Regards,

Comment: just do an `echo %PATH%` and check if powerShell is present, Mostly in your case it will not be there so just add it.

Comment: I managed to run a PS script from CodeCommit, i'm using Jenkins under Windows. but i'm still having an issue to browse the script folder i've used sparse checkout paths but no success with /folder/folde2 or folder/folde2/

Answer (score 1):

For the envirionment I am in I have had to do it the following way to get it to work.

`Build Step - Windows Powershell` with the following code

```
$File_Path_Name = $ENV:WORKSPACE + "\Folder\ScriptName.ps1"

Powershell -File $File_Path_Name
```

You will also need to make sure you have `Git` configured properly under `Source Code Management`. `Repository URL`, `Credentials`, and the `Branch`. Also need to make sure the credentials used have the proper access to GitHub(in my case)

Comment: I managed to run a PS script from CodeCommit, i'm using Jenkins under Windows. but i'm still having an issue to browse the script folder i've used sparse checkout paths but no success with /folder/folde2 or folder/folde2/